# I have figured out solutions to my closed, unanswered question, on my own. Does anyone care to have them?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to work around the possible regression issue in Firefox 81 that breaks my javascript: URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039752/how-to-work-around-the-possible-regression-issue-in-firefox-81-that-breaks-my-ja)

I don't know if I should bother, but maybe someone out there might find a use for the solutions. I may not know how to write a good question, and I may not even know how to write a good answer, but my solutions/workarounds are sound.

If I get a chance to post my solutions, I probably wouldn't bother to write detailed explanations about everything, but I think the example workarounds are more or less self-explanatory.

I don't think I have enough reputation here to do anything anymore, so what, if anything, should I do? I'm not asking for a favor.

I feel the community let me down, but I can be understanding. Even if the community members don't care for my solutions, maybe some internet/google/guest users might find the solutions useful. I guess I could always post my solutions on some other non SO non-SE site/forum.

Comment: The question has one reopen vote of the three it needs. Perhaps a little patience is all you need here.

Comment: It looks like a reasonable question after the edits, and could be useful to others. Can anyone with newer versions of FF reproduce the problem? If so, it looks suitable for reopening

Comment: @CertainPerformance There's a [bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1667009) so someone will likely look into it and fix it at some point.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Already been reproduced: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1667009#c4

Comment: @MehBMe - if you want a question to be evaluated for reopening, try [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for faster response than meta. Although you need 20 rep to post there, so I suggest at least answering/asking a well-received question first. P.s. please don't address others in posts, if they are to stay, they should become a part of the knowledge base we are trying to build here. The current shape of the question is still borderline to open, but I voted to open it (assuming you will provide a detailed answer following the community guidelines).

Comment: @OlegValter I do not think that room will take request for one's own posts.

Comment: @Scratte well, I take it back, it is only sort of allowed by rule 15, par 4 (not as a request) :) Although that particular question is already out of the question due to par 6 in any case.

Comment: @OlegValter All true. Your insight and reference to the rules made me smile :) Though I know of users having success with asking what they can improve on their posts.

Comment: @OlegValter, Thanks for the show of support. I'll try to add explanations to my answer, though I may need to revise it over time to get it up to expectations. I may need advise on how to improve. Same applies to question. Because it was radically changed over edits, the previous community suggestions may no longer apply (such as about obfuscated code).

Comment: @Scratte my pleasure :) Thanks for the comment, btw - my knowledge of the rules got rusty, so as soon as you asked, something tingled me that what I am advising may be borderline at best. MehBMe - please, try to word the requests on meta less confrontational next time around, this is pretty much guaranteed to yield a more welcome reception. Re:advice - just follow the [guidelines on answering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question), and you should be good to go.

Comment: "...what, if anything, should I do?" Edit your question and make it ontopic. Then wait until it gets reopened. Then answer it. You already did all of that and it didn't take very long in my opinion.